# Run two commands every x seconds loop

Tags: java

I have two commands: `System.out.println("something");` and `System.out.println("another thing");`.

I want to execute them sequentially in a continuous loop as follows:

1. Execute `System.out.println("something");`.
2. Wait X seconds.
3. Execute `System.out.println("another thing");`.
4. Wait X seconds.
5. Execute `System.out.println("something");`.
6. And so on...

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        System.out.println("something");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("another thing");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("something");
```

Or use a framework that supports triggering of tasks

Answer (score 0):

Just as a thought, it may be better to use a timer of sorts. Below is a simple [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/Timer.html) which runs an individual thread task every *n* number of seconds. This allows your main code to run uninterrupted. See the below example:

```
public class MyApplication {

    // Declare a Utility Timer
    java.util.Timer arrayElementsTimer = new java.util.Timer();
    
    // Place the strings you want to cycle every n seconds into a String[] array:
    String[] strings = {"Something...", "Something else..."};

    // Number of seconds between string displays:
    int secondsPerCycle = 2;

    // Constructor:
    public MyApplication() {
        /* Start the utility timer... 
           Timer start delay will be:     secondsPerCycle * 1000 (in milliseconds).
           Timer cycle time will also be: secondsPerCycle * 1000 (in milliseconds).
        */
        runTimer();
    }
    
    private void runTimer() {
        // Schedule a timer task:
        arrayElementsTimer.schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
            // Keeps track of the array element to display:
            int count = 0;  

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Display the strings[] array element at index count to console window:
                System.out.println(strings[count]);
                // Increment count by 1:
                count++;
                // If count equals the length of strings[] array then reset count to 0:
                if (count == strings.length) {
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
        }, (secondsPerCycle * 1000), (secondsPerCycle * 1000));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* App started this way to avoid the need for statics 
           unless we really want them:        */
        new MyApplication().startApp(args);
    }

    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        // Get input from User - Ask to hit ENTER key:
        java.util.Scanner userInput = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("<< Press ENTER To Stop Timer >>");
        String input = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("<< Enter Key Hit >>");
        // Stop the utility timer:
        arrayElementsTimer.cancel();
        System.out.println("<< Timer Canceled >>");
    }
}
```

Your console output should look something like:

```
<< Press ENTER To Stop Timer >>
Something...
Something else...
Something...
Something else...
Something...

<< Enter Key Hit >>
<< Timer Canceled >>
```